# What SOFTWARE could I use to encode to this spec?

Tags: encoding, software-recommendation, post-production, mpeg, broadcast

Thanks in advance!

It's an **mpeg** transport stream in a **.ts** wrapper. Layout would be as follows:

**Video** (MPEG2, 80Mbps, CBR, All I Frame,422@HL) 
**Audio1** (Track1/PID1) 1 pair LPCM(SMPTE 302M)48kHz 
**Audio2** (Track2/PID2) 1 pair LPCM(SMPTE 302M)48kHz 
**Audio3** (Track3/PID3) 1 pair LPCM(SMPTE 302M)48kHz 
**Audio4** (Track4/PID4) 1 pair LPCM(SMPTE 302M)48kHz

FFmpeg is out because it won't encode LPCM into .ts.
 I'd rather not go down the AVISynth wormhole because I'm Mac based but if there is a CLEAR solution (as opposed to random AVISynth fiddling) by trying that route, I'd definitely be willing to give it a go.
 I tried AME/Adobe.
I tried Telestream.
 I tried Resolve. 
 I haven't tried Compressor *this go around* but I know it's there to try if I don't hear anything else.

I've done this a bunch with hardware encoders but I'm on my own now and a dedicated HW encoder is not in the budget for this project.
 I look forward to and appreciate your input!

Comment: What exactly did you try in each of those programs? Please share the full ffmpeg command and output. Which Telestream product? Did you try contacting their technical support?

Comment: I appreciate your response! In the interim I corresponded with one of (I think) the developers of ffmpeg and they were able to clarify some information regarding the software’s ability to encode 302M audio into .ts from non-.ts sources.  It also APPEARS that I can do this in AWS/elemental so I’m going to  do some testing with that.  I’ll report back if I have any noteworthy results.  Cheers!